# android image upload

Tags: android

hello i am new in android devlopment 
    i want to know how to upload an image in android 
    i dont found any usefull tutorial for this 
    can u give me some instruction,pls,help me out.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want to do with this image?
There are many ways to work with images, and I need to choose the one most suitable for your needs. With best,

Comment: All that you want is [here](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I built this lil methods for you:

```
private boolean handlePicture(String filePath, String mimeType) {       
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

    byte[] buffer;

    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    String urlString = "http://www.yourwebserver.com/youruploadscript.php";

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { }
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);            

        outStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        outStream.writeBytes(addParam("someparam", "content of some param", twoHyphens, boundary, lineEnd));                

        outStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"" + filePath +"\"" + lineEnd + "Content-Type: " + mimeType + lineEnd + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);          
        outStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

          while (bytesRead > 0) {
              outStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

          outStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
          outStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();  
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("DEBUG", "[MalformedURLException while sending a picture]");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("DEBUG", "[IOException while sending a picture]"); 
    }

    try {
           inStream = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );
           String str;

           while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
               if(str=="1") {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   return false;
               }
           }
           inStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e){
          Log.e("DEBUG", "[IOException while sending a picture and receiving the response]");
      }
    return false;
}

private String addParam(String key, String value, String twoHyphens, String boundary, String lineEnd) {
        return twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd + lineEnd + value + lineEnd;
}
```

Should work so far. On your webserver you need some PHP Script which returns a "1" for a successful upload and something else for an error. I also suggest to do this in a ASyncTask, to prevent blocking the user during the uploading.
On the webserver side you've got a file in the name "uploadedfile". Hope that helps!

Comment: Would you update your answer after reading this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926550/8418 (I was trying to upload to App Engine and after that fix.. it worked!)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use this code today, but the lines `outStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());` and `inStream = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );` are throwing IOExceptions. I have no idea why! can you help?

Comment: What kind of IO Exception is it? Where do you use the code? Emulator or Phone, with an SD Card or not? Does the Connection work?

Comment: Hy... can i get the php function if you don't mind... thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a tutorial bout it. Here you have an example: np.

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: jmaster
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Referer: http://shop/index.php/index/register/b/
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------19187836022413
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-Host: jmaster
X-Forwarded-Server: jmaster
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 38682
-----------------------------19187836022413
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="Clipboard02.png"
Content-Type: image/png
‰PNG
?
... and this is how it goes.
-----------------------------19187836022413
and you're ending transmission.
----------------------------19187836022413

hope this helps.