# App Engine Blobstore - Upload file from Android

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, http-post, webapp2

I have an App Engine application that stores users profile pictures using the blobstore. When I upload images from a form in Chrome it works fine. When I try to upload an image from an Android application it fails. Contrary to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893268/appengine-blobstore-upload-failing-with-a-request-that-works-in-the-development), using the android app to upload to my dev server also doesn't work.

My app engine server follows the guide at [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/). My android upload code is based upon apache httpcore and httpmime from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk/22803149#22803149).

This is the successful request from Chrome:

self.request.params:

```
UnicodeMultiDict([(u'usersid', u'xxxxx'), (u'profilePicUpload', FieldStorage(u'profilePicUpload', u'image.png'))])
```

self.request.headers:

```
{'Origin': 'https://site.appspot.com', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
'X-Appengine-Blobchunksize': '9521', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'X-Appengine-Blobupload': 'true', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.132 Safari/537.36',
'Host': 'site.appspot.com', 'Cookie': 'xxxxx', 'Content_Type': 'multipart/form-data;
boundary=001a11333c426e860104f972b1fc', 'Referer': 'https://site.appspot.com/profile',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=001a11333c426e860104f972b1fc',
'X-Appengine-Country': 'ZZ', 'X-Appengine-Blobsize': '9521'}
```

self.request.body:

```
--001a11333c426e860104f972b1fc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="usersid"

xxxxx
--001a11333c426e860104f972b1fc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profilePicUpload"; filename="image.png"
Content-type: message/external-body; blob-key="xxxxx" ...
```

This is the unsuccessful request from Android:

self.request.params:

```
UnicodeMultiDict([(u'usersid', u'xxxxx'), (u'profilePicUpload', FieldStorage(u'profilePicUpload', u'image.jpg'))])
```

self.request.headers:

```
{'Content_Length': '2103726', 'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)',
'Host': 'site.appspot.com', 'Content_Type': 'multipart/form-data;
boundary=cn2wRMd4fQphmeBcsYsjjJH7wfDtPm', 'X-Appengine-Region': 'eng', 'X-Appengine-City':
'crawley', 'X-Appengine-Citylatlong': '51.109140,-0.187227', 'Content-Type':
'multipart/form-data; boundary=cn2wRMd4fQphmeBcsYsjjJH7wfDtPm', 'X-Appengine-Country': 'GB'}
```

self.request.body:

```
--cn2wRMd4fQphmeBcsYsjjJH7wfDtPm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="usersid"

xxxxx
--cn2wRMd4fQphmeBcsYsjjJH7wfDtPm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profilePicUpload"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-type: application/octet-stream
....
```

self.get_uploads() returns an empty list for the second case. Any ideas why?

As you can see, I don't have a missing space before filename as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893268/appengine-blobstore-upload-failing-with-a-request-that-works-in-the-development).

Comment: What's with the `Content_Type` header? The standard content type header is `Content-Type`, but you are sending both?

Comment: I don't add that myself @PeterKnego. It seems to be added by both my HTML form in Chrome and httpcore in Android. I had a brief look in the httpcore library code and couldn't find reference to it. It only mentions Content-Type. Unless it is somehow automatically added to the request by App Engine?